# Recovery Services vault cannot be deleted. Azure portal menu is not allowing to disable soft delete. As it is read only now

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-resource-manager, azure-monitoring, azure-backup-vault

****Az104 lab 10  Have created 2 backup items in Recovery Services Vault but unable to remove/delete it**

- Azure VM & Azure Backup Agent**
- On trying to remove or delete these items; since soft-delete is
  enabled (Say for 14 days). Facing error on Manual as well as
  PowerShell Delete procedures.
- PowerShell seems to be not updated with Current menu options in Azure
  Portal. I used the below; get the status as success but VM and Agent
  still appear in my subscription.

Below is the PS I used

```
Undo-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItemDeletion -Item $myBKpItem -VaultId $myVaultID -Force


Disable-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProtection -Item $myBkpItem -RemoveRecoveryPoints -VaultId $myVaultID -Force
```

And ms-learn docs the below PowerShell seems to not work

```
Set-AzRecoveryServicesVaultProperty -VaultId $myVaultID -SoftDeleteFeatureState Disable
```

It gives a result of Bad Request saying -SoftDeleteFeatureState does not exists for Set-AzRecoveryServicesVaultProperty

What may be possible ways to delete soft-delete enabled backup VM on the recovery services vault.

Answer (score 1):

So I replicated your problem as best as I could, this is what I did:

Create RSV, add VM into RSV with soft delete enabled, then deleted and had the VM in soft delete state. I went into the RSV and manually clicked undelete, which put the VM back into the RSV and then ran the below turn off soft delete:

Set-AzRecoveryServicesVaultProperty -VaultId "myvault" -SoftDeleteFeatureState Disable

I then ran the below to remove the VM from the vault and remove any associated backup data:

```
# VARIABLES
[String]$rgBackup = ""
[String]$vaultName = ""
# $vaultId = "[RECOVERY SERVICE VAULT ID]"

$vault = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault -ResourceGroupName $rgBackup -Name $vaultName

$containerBackup = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem -BackupManagementType    AzureVM -WorkloadType AzureVM -VaultId $vault.ID | Where-Object {$_.DeleteState -eq "NotDeleted"}

$containerbackup| ForEach-Object -ThrottleLimit 10 -Parallel {write-host -fore green $_.name; Disable-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProtection -Item $_ -VaultId "" -RemoveRecoveryPoints -Force -Verbose} 

Write-Host "********************************* FIN *********************************************************"
```

And then I ran the below to force delete the RSV:

az backup vault delete --name --resource-group --force

You should just need to update RG and RSV names and IDs and hopefully it should work for you.

Comment: Cloud Shell says "Set-AzRecoveryServicesVaultProperty -VaultId "myvault" -SoftDeleteFeatureState Disable" is BadRequest. And I seem be stuck with Undelete state even after executing the above 4 cmdlets

Comment: Used this for the last cmdlet "$containerbackup| ForEach-Object -ThrottleLimit 10 -Parallel {write-host -fore green $_.name; Disable-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProtection -Item $_ -VaultId $vault.ID -RemoveRecoveryPoints -Force -Verbose} " - Still stuck with the VM.

Comment: Tried again a few times.Still did not work